# How can I set specific step in a job restart if take more than 7 minutes running? SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have setup a job in SSMS with 3 steps based in SSIS packages (ETL), but every certain time, the second step is taking longer than expected.

I'm trying to achieve that in the second step:
[image]

But every certain time, I'm getting that:
[image]

Comment: I'm no expert, but can jobs start other jobs? If so, can they do it asynchronously?

Comment: The question is unclear about what you are trying to achieve, please add snippet of jobs and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Ok, I just post some images so you can understand.

Comment: Is the three steps in the SSIS package?  Or it's three job steps and each step does a different SSIS package?  Question is a bit confusing

Comment: Is just 1 job with 3 ssis steps.

Comment: It's three job steps and each step does a different SSIS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Only one instance of a SQL Agent job can be active at any one time.
- sp_start_job will be an asynchronous call - fire and forget
- sp_stop_job will terminate an existing agent job
- Agent job information is stored in msdb.dbo.sysjobs and currently running tasks are in msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity

Putting all that together, you will want to

1. Create a new SQL Agent job called JobKiller
2. Modify the existing job to start JobKiller immediately prior to the SSIS package begining (so step 2 that you want to kill after 7 minutes is actually step 3 and we should plan accordingly)

The JobKiller definition would be the following

```
-- Wait for 7 minutes
WAITFOR DELAY '00:07:00';

-- Is our job still running 
-- verify that last completed step was JobKiller (2)
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT
    *
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS S
    INNER JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS S2
        ON S2.job_id = S.job_id
WHERE
    S.name = 'LongRunningJob'
    AND S2.last_executed_step_id = 2
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, S2.start_execution_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 7
)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job
        @job_name = 'LongRunningJob';
END
```

Similar to ElementZero's approach but no tempdb object mucking about.

Comment: How can I modify the existing job to start with job killer, because there isn't a step that can call a job...

Comment: and when you say, to add the definition it has to be as T-sql script rigth?

Comment: Correct, add a new step of type TSQL to start another job

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this I would probably start another job that would check for a lock or a table entry or something. This might seem kinda hacky but it should work...

> ### Job 1 (named 'ETL')
>
> **Step 2 (named 'Start Monitor')** - this is a new step

```
-- Since we'll use this for locking, make sure only one exists
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..SSISPackageRunnerLock') is not null then 
   drop table SSISPackageRunnerLock

-- Create a global temp table that will exist till this step is done
CREATE TABLE tempdb..SSISPackageRunnerLock(id int)

-- Start our monitor job
sp_start_job @job_name = 'ETL Monitor'
```

> **Step 3** - this is your existing step (the step that is currently 'step2')

Kick off SSIS package step

> **Step 4** -- this is a new step

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..SSISPackageRunnerLock') is not null then 
       drop table tempdb..SSISPackageRunnerLock
```

> ### Job 2 (named 'ETL Monitor')
>
> **Step 1**

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:07:00' - Wait for seven minutes

/***
Does the table that we made in step 2 of the other job still exist?  
If so the step must be still running
***/
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..SSISPackageRunnerLock') is not null  
BEGIN
   -- Kill the other job
   sp_stop_job @job_name = 'ETL'

   WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00' -- wait a minute for it to stop

   -- Start it back up on that step to "restart" it
   sp_start_job @job_name = 'ETL', @step_name = 'Start Monitor'
END
```

I should note that this will basically create an infinite loop of step 2 of job 1 IF it never completes within seven minutes.  You might want to add like sending an email or something after the sp_start_job so you are aware that the monitor job had to be used (and you would get endless emails if it was constantly being used).

Comment: Should I create 2 more jobs based on the T-sql script or how can I do it with my current job?

Comment: Kind of but let say that my current job is named ETL and the step that has issue is named 'step2' How can I implement that with your code?, because I can see that I will have to create 2 more jobs? or create 2 more steps with that code??

Comment: Ok edited again (really it's just name changes).  You don't have to create two more jobs, just add two more steps to your existing job and then make another job to monitor the first job step.